# Adding VIM plugins to Janus setup

Tags: ruby, vim, plugins, macvim, janus

I recently switched over to using [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) from a custom set of vim plugins and .vimrc. I'm really enjoying the setup, but one thing I'm missing is the automatic completion of blocks in Ruby.

For example, when I type:

```
def method <enter>
```

It would complete the block:

```
def method
  # cursor here
end
```

I was using some of Tim Pope's plugins and can't recall which one provided the functionality (Rails maybe?) Is there a way to get this functionality using Janus? Is there a reason why someone wouldn't want this? It seems really convenient to have.

Comment: Janus has since added endwise to project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to janus documentation [documentation](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus):

If you want to add additional Vim plugins you can do so by adding a ~/.janus.rake like so:

```
vim_plugin_task "zencoding", "git://github.com/mattn/zencoding-vim.git"
vim_plugin_task "minibufexpl", "git://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim.git"
```

ant then just run rake or run rake for the pluging you setup, on `~/.vim`, for example:

```
rake zenconding
```

Comment: Does this work anymore? I'm not able to find that rake task. The only reference to plugin I found in Janus doc is installing the plugin in ~/.janus folder, but I'm having trouble getting that to work too.

Comment: Can you expand on this? The instructions are very difficult for me to follow. It looks like their docs are saying make a file called .janus.rake in your home directory (~) and in that file simply write those lines. Then what?

Comment: I've being using Vundle (https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) these days instead of Janus.

Answer (score 6):

You're talking about [endwise](http://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise/).

Presumably you could just add this repo to the Janus rakefile, however I've not tested.  This is likely not included in Janus because this can pretty much be emulated with [snipMate](http://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) which is included in Janus.

Comment: Thanks! I tried snipMate but it's not exactly what I want so I put endwise in ~/.vim/plugin. That did the trick, but what I'll probably end up doing is just forking Janus and adding this.

Answer (score 6):

The [janus customization documentation](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/wiki/Customization) currently reccommends using the ~/.janus directory for vim plugins.

You can use git clone to install vim plugins into the ~/.janus directory. E.g.

```
cd ~/.janus
git clone https://github.com/vim-scripts/Rename2.git rename2
```

The old method for customization, using rakefile is in a [separate branch](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/tree/rakefile) that is not maintained.

Comment: haven't gotten that to work, the directory is there but it doesn't seem to take effect, trying to install zencoding

Comment: or even a way to debug this would be nice

Comment: Note: Plugins must be added within a containing directory as would be done by the git commands above, and not the bare my_plugin.vim file (as would be done in with Vim in `~/.vim/plugin/)`. Ex. `~/.janus/vim-gnupg/plugin/gnupg.vim`, not `~/.janus/gnupg.vim`.