# gtk-vim-syntax with Janus

Tags: c, vim, gtk, glib

I recently fell in love with Janus, I can't live without it anymore. I decided to do some C programming and came across this:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1000.

I have absolutely no idea how to get it to work with Janus, I've spent hours experimenting and researching but to no avail.

I came across this:
[Adding VIM plugins to Janus setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808059/adding-vim-plugins-to-janus-setup), and found the same Vim library on Github. After doing everything twice and making sure I did everything right, it still didn't work.

Comment: Ssssh; when romainl sees your profession of love, he'll go ballistic :-) Seriously, this is very simple in plain Vim; if it turns out to be so difficult with Janus, that's a huge argument against it (even if it's just poor documentation), isn't it?!

Comment: Janus and its friends are the absolute worst way to configure Vim: hard to debug, hard to maintain, hard to augment, hard to customize… and that's without even considering the sillyness of giving someone else complete control over your Vim experience. @IngoKarkat, ;-) I was writing this rant when I saw your comment. Thanks for lowering my blood pressure with a joke!

Comment: @romainl: Cheers, I immediately had to think about you (and your likely reaction) when I read this question. I've never put my hands on any Vim distribution; but from the questions we get I can only support your strong position against these; keep up the evangelism :-)

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for the reactions. I'll self answer this with your comments in mind. I love a lot of the plugins that Janus comes with, but it seems it would be better to install these plugins manually as to give myself complete control over my Vim. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use Janus then you must use Janus by itself without any additional customization. If you would like to use the plugins or themes that Janus provides it is wise to install them manually as to give yourself full control over your own Vim.